# Definition of curvilinear coordinates?

Tags: definition, coordinate-systems

Please can someone give me a formal definition of curvilinear coordinates, preferably with as source. The once that I have found don't seem to be very formal.

Comment: What's wrong with the wiki pages on this topic?  It looks pretty extensive.

Comment: @GregoryGrant They don't give a formal definition, in the first line it says ' A coordinate system,..., where the coordinate lines may be curved.' But this is not very formal,  or even a definition, I can't clear definition else where on the page.

Comment: What about this page? http://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/Chap3/Chap3-5/printversion.pdf